# Rabbit mq messages processed before acknowledgement

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

I have an issue with my rabbit mq setup using node.

A brief gist of the code is

```
queue.subscribe({ack: true}, function(msg) {
    // Do some processing
    queue.shift(false);
}
```

I expect messages to be read and applied serially -> the second message should start processing only after first message is applied and acknowledged.

But this is not happening. I see that in some cases the second message starts processing before the first message is acknowledged. The default prefetch count is 1 so this should not happen.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try to make the queue exclusive to ensure there are no dead subscribers that keep nacking messages. https://www.rabbitmq.com/semantics.html#ordering Generally speaking relying on the message order is not the best idea: https://twitter.com/mathiasverraes/status/632260618599403520?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fmartinfowler.com%2Fbliki%2FTwoHardThings.html but if you can reliable reproduce, please describe the *some cases* in details.

Comment: the order of the messages is not an issue here. but according to my understanding the consumer process should not pick up the next message before it acknowledges the previous message

Comment: Are you saying you can confirm the same listener starts to process another message before acking the previous one even with exclusive subscriber option?

Comment: yes. by using console logs I see this behaviour